# Confusion in Pointer to the object

Tags: c++

In the following code, I had defined map of int and object of class A. I defined two functions, funwithPointer and funwithoutPointer. As you can see, I am trying to increment vote in the object of class and adding that to map. If I use the pointer of the object then on calling 3rd time I get vote of 2 while on declaring object without pointer(funwithoutPointer), I cannot increase the vote beyond 1, no matter how many time I call that function. What's the problem ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
class A{
    public:
        int x;int vote;
        A(int a):x(a),vote(0){}
        void change(){
            cout<<vote<<endl;
            vote++;}
};
void funwithPointer(map<int,A>& m){
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(m.find(i)==m.end()){
            A* a=new A(10);
            a->change();
            m.insert(pair<int,A>(i,*a));
        }
        else{
            A* a=&m.find(i)->second;
            a->change();
        }
    }
}
void funwithoutPointer(map<int,A>& m){
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(m.find(i)==m.end()){
            A a= A(10);
            a.change();
            m.insert(pair<int,A>(i,a));
        }
        else{
            A a=m.find(i)->second;
            a.change();
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    map<int,A> m;
    funwithoutPointer(m);
    funwithoutPointer(m);
    funwithoutPointer(m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In function

```
void funwithoutPointer(map<int,A>& m){
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(m.find(i)==m.end()){
            A a= A(10);
            a.change();
            m.insert(pair<int,A>(i,a));
        }
        else{
            A a=m.find(i)->second;
            a.change();
        }
    }
}
```

in statements

```
            A a=m.find(i)->second;
            a.change();
```

you create a new object of type A and increase its data member. It has nothing common with the corresponding object in the map. Change these statements the following way

```
            A &a = m.find(i)->second;
            a.change();
```

that is use a reference to the object in the map. Or instead of these two statements you could write the following way

```
            m.find(i)->second.change();
```

As you can see between these two statements

```
            A &a = m.find(i)->second;
            a.change();
```

and statements in the first function

```
            A* a=&m.find(i)->second;
            a->change();
```

there are many common. Either you use a reference to an object that to change it or a pointer to this object

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in this line:

```
A a=m.find(i)->second;
```

You are making a copy of object in the map, named `a` and then trying to modify that copy. Simple solution could be to use reference:

```
A &a=m.find(i)->second;
```

Notice that you code is pretty ineffective, faster (and simpler solution) could be:

```
auto f = map.find( i );
if( f == map.end() ) 
    f = m.insert( std::make_pair( i, A(10) ) ).first;
f->second.change();
```

This eliminates completely unnecessary extra call to `std::map::find()` which is pretty expensive.

Another, even more effective solution (thanks to Chris Jester-Young):

```
auto f = map.lower_bound( i );
if( f == map.end() || f->first != i ) 
    f = m.insert( f, std::make_pair( i, A(10) ) );
f->second.change();
```

Comment: Even faster is to use `lower_bound` instead of `find`, then if the result is the same as `end()` or the key is not the same as `i`, then do a hinted insertion. :-)

Comment: Thus: `auto f(map.find(i)); if (f == map.end() || f->first != i) m.insert(f, std::make_pair(...)); else ...`

Comment: @Slava What if I use, m.insert(pair<int,A>(i,a)); after calling change() function again. That is I am inserting the updated version of a.

Comment: @user3747190, yes noticed that, fixed

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young added your variant, if you want to put it into your own answer I will remove it.

Comment: Thanks! No, I don't intend to post my own answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this:

```
void funwithoutPointer(map<int,A>& m){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        map<int,A>::iterator iFind = m.find(i);
        if(iFind==m.end()){
            A a(10);
            a.change();
            m[i] = a;
        }
        else{
            iFind->second.change();
        }
    }
}
```

This will insert a new object into the map if not found or allow you to modify the actual object in the map if it is found